# Moment.js issue with Invalid Date

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am trying to validate a concatenated date time string using Moment.js.
I am using strict parsing for validation and below code returns **false**:

**moment("March 1, 2019 1:1 am","MMMM D, YYYY h:m a", true).isValid()**

I tried using various combiantions such as:

1. MMM DD, YYYY hh:mm a
2. MMM DD, YYYY h:mm a
3. MMM D, YYYY h:m a

I am unable to understand what is the mistake that I am making?

Comment: The example you brought in bold returns true, what's the issue?

Comment: Its working. Check code at https://jsfiddle.net/nge21v9d/1/

Comment: Yes, it is working. I might have made some mistake while changing the format.